# How to exchange Woocommerce profile photo and WP user avatar

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, avatar

I am using WP User Avatar plugin and Woocommerce Profile Photo plugin together.

To upload avatar from woocommerce edit account front end, I am using Woocommerce Profile Photo Plugin.

https://webfor99.com/woocommerce-custom-profile-picture-avatar-plugin/

And to show more free options for user avatar, I am using WP User Avatar.

But between them no connections now, so I want to use uploaded image by Woocommerce Profile Photo for WP user avatar. Below is what I did.

```
function change_avatar( $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt ) {  
    $all_users = get_users(array('meta_key' => 'profile_pic',));
    
    foreach ($all_users as $user) {
        $user_id = $user->ID;
        ?><pre><?php var_dump( $user_id ); ?></pre><?php
        $profile_pic = get_user_meta($user_id, 'profile_pic', true);
        ?><pre><?php var_dump( $profile_pic ); ?></pre><?php
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'wp_user_avatar', $profile_pic);
    }
}
add_action('profile_update', 'change_avatar');
add_action('user_register', 'change_avatar');
```

Used `update_user_meta()` to change avatar image but not working. As you can see I did some debug works to check if it works. Before `update_user_meta()` it works correctly. But user avatar is not changing.

[image]

It is getting correct uploaded image ID but avatar is not changing.

Please let me get some more help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action('profile_update', 'change_avatar');
add_action('user_register', 'change_avatar');
```

This code will not work. Please use `add_filter('get_avatar', 'change_avatar', 10, 5)` instead.

I tested and it works.

Comment: Thanks @Lee, I tried it before but for me it didn't work. Please tell me more about how to avoid current issues.